# Nested routing in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following module structure:

1- RootModule

With routing as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'app', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

2- AppModule

With routing as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { 
        path: 'app', 
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'index',
                pathMatch: 'full'
           }
       ]
   }
```

];

Also, `AppModule` imports `MainModule` which is only a routing module and is configured as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
               path: 'index',
               loadChildren: '.\/..\/modules\/index\/index.module#IndexModule'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'index',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
       ]
  }
```

];

Now, `RootComponent` is the starting point:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template:  "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

The `AppComponent` is defined as:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-quick-sidebar></app-quick-sidebar>
```

Finally, `MainComponent` is defined as:

```
<app-header-nav></app-header-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The whole point is to route the application to /index component in such a way to pass through `RooComponent` --> `AppComponent` --> `MainComponent` --> `IndexComponent`

So far, with the above routes, `AppComponent` is bypassed!

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a stackblitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current routes configuration, `MainComponent` is not configured in the children array of `AppComponent`'s path. So why would it appear in its template?

Right now you routing configuration will work like this:

- navigating to `/app` will get you to `AppComponent`
- navigating to `/index` will get you to the `IndexComponent`.

To achieve the desired behavior of `RooComponent` --> `AppComponent` --> `MainComponent` --> `IndexComponent`, your routes configuration should look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ 
  path: '', 
  component: AppComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
      path: 'index',
      loadChildren: '.\/..\/modules\/index\/index.module#IndexModule'
    }]
  }]
}];
```